# What types can "unsigned" be used with? When is "signed" needed?

Tags: c++, types

```
    int
    short
    long
    long long
    unsigned int / unsigned
    unsigned short
    unsigned long
    unsigned long long
    char
    bool
    float 
    double
```

I just never get the limit. Are these all or are there more like:

```
unsigned char
unsigned bool
unsigned float 
unsigned double
```

or any other?

I have a  tomorrow and I want to be clear with the basics.

Comment: Take at look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types.

Comment: Don't bother providing links, I have a text book for that matter. Just answer my question. Yes or No? This is really frustrating. Nothing has been explicitly mentioned anywhere.

Comment: maybe and maybe not. Difficult to see the future is.

Comment: When we say int, is it a signed int or unsigned int?

Comment: What would make you think an int is unsigned, unless it says `unsigned int` ?

Comment: Because I had the balls to ask such a dumb question and I may get like -9999999 down votes, I want to get all my doubts cleared in this question please.

Comment: So there is no such thing called a signed int, right? It's just int and unsigned it, correct?

Comment: BTW, the link showed that int, signed and signed int were the same thing.

Comment: You can explicitly write `signed int` if you'd like, but it is generally equivalent to simply writing `int`.

Comment: So, how many primitive data types are there in all? This is a quiz question that may be asked tomorrow.

Comment: Somebody told me we can have something like long long and then long long long and  also long long long long...so can we have infinite number of them?

Comment: dude, just rtfm. it's all in there. or read your textbook.

Comment: There is a practical limit; if you try to compile something like that, you'll probably get an error like this: `'long long long' is too long for GCC`.

Comment: Only `long` and `long long` are standard right now. Also, looking at the types you mentioned, there are no `unsigned float` or `unsigned double`. Only integer types (`char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`) can be `unsigned` or `signed`.

Comment: The language used in your since-deleted comment is not welcome here.  Keep it courteous.

Answer (score 0):

> I just never get the limit. Are these all[?] ...
>
> Don't bother providing links, I have a text book for that matter. Just
>   answer my question. Yes or No? This is really frustrating. Nothing has
>   been explicitly mentioned anywhere.

No.

Integer and character types (e.g., int, short, char, wchar_t, etc.) support signedness modifiers (signed/unsigned) and can therefore all be unsigned.

Floating point types (e.g., float, double, long double) do not support signedness modifiers and therefore cannot be unsigned or explicitly signed, for that matter.

**A few examples of valid expressions:**

```
char
unsigned char
int
signed int
unsigned short
unsigned long long
```

**A few examples of invalid expressions:**

```
signed double
unsigned double
unsigned float
signed unsigned int
```

Comment: By the way, there are 3 types of `char`:  `unsigned char`, `signed char` and `char`.  The type `char` is compiler dependent and will either be signed or unsigned.

Comment: Could the down-vote please be explained? Does my answer contain inaccurate information?